# Grouping and counting SQL query with Retrosheet baseball data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using [Retrosheet data](http://www.techgraphs.com/building-a-retrosheet-database-part-3-the-easymac-way/) to do some SQL queries on baseball stats.

I'm able to make a query that will return individual performances just fine. The example below looks for all games `GAME_ID` where Roger Clemens `clemr001` appeared and recorded a strikeout `EVENT_CD = '3'`. Each event is its own line in the database, so I group the strikeout events together and count them up.

```
SELECT `GAME_ID` AS 'Game',`PIT_ID` AS 'Pitcher',COUNT(*) AS 'Strikeouts'
FROM `events` 
WHERE `PIT_ID` = 'clemr001' 
AND `EVENT_CD` = '3'
GROUP BY `GAME_ID`
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

The result is somethings like this:

```
Game          Pitcher   Strikeouts
DET199609180  clemr001  20
BOS198604290  clemr001  20
TOR199808250  clemr001  18
etc...
```

My problem is creating a SQL query that will return the number of strikeouts from each pitcher in each game.

The preferred result would be like the table below, where the results are grouped by game, but each individual pitching performance is counted up using the strikeout event code.

```
Game          Pitcher   Strikeouts
DET199609180  clemr001  20
DET199609180  bluev001  19
DET199609180  peavj001  2
NYN196405312  rheij001  9
NYN196405312  garcj004  5
NYN196405312  wilsd102  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to:

```
GROUP BY `GAME_ID`, `PIT_ID`
```

Answer (score 0):

So basicly something like this?

The following code should select all games, pitchers and strikeouts, grouped by game id and ordered by strikeouts.

```
SELECT `GAME_ID` AS 'Game',`PIT_ID` AS 'Pitcher',COUNT(*) AS 'Strikeouts'
FROM `events` 
WHERE `EVENT_CD` = '3'
GROUP BY `GAME_ID`, `PIT_ID`
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: I just notised you edited your question.. will update in a bit.

Comment: Yes, definitely something like that. The only problem is that query will return a "flattened" result with only ONE pitcher being returned.